# pytest requests to fastapi in a separate process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pytest, fastapi

I am trying to have working tests for an API written with FastAPI.

I start the service in a separate process, run the tests with requests to the service, and check if the results are as expected.

I have extracted the key parts into a minimal working example, in the PD.

Running the MWE with the main file works fine. The tests fail, though.

- Why do the tests fail?
- How should we test APIs?

PD: the code is [in a GIST](https://gist.github.com/trylks/1c924e244635551ea7e1a5385b4d25e6), but now also here:

### README.md

```markdown
# Minimal example to ask in StackOverflow

Pytest does not allow to start a process with a service and tests requests to it,
  at least not in the most straightforward way IMHO.

I may be missing something, or I may be doing something wrong.
Hence, I share this short code in a gist, to ask.

## How to run it

The dependencies are: `fastapi pytest requests uvicorn`.
You may install them with your package / environment manager of choice,
  or use `pipenv install` with the provided `Pipfile`.

To run the code in the environment (e.g. `pipenv shell`), run: `python3 mwe.py`.
You should see everything is `OK`.

To run the test, run in the environment: `pytest`.
This does not work for me, the request times out.
```

### mwe.py

```python
import fastapi, multiprocessing, requests, time, uvicorn

app = fastapi.FastAPI()


@app.get('/ok')
def ok():
    return 'OK'


class service:
    def __enter__(self):
        def run_service():
            uvicorn.run('mwe:app', host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, reload=True)
        self.service = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_service)
        self.service.start()
        time.sleep(10)

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.service.terminate()


def main():
    with service():
        return requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/ok').ok


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(''[main()])
```

### Pipfile

```ini
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
pytest = "*"
fastapi = "*"
requests = "*"
uvicorn = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.10"
python_full_version = "3.10.6"
```

### test_mwe.py

```python
from mwe import main

def test_main():
    assert main()
```

Comment: Please include all the relevant details and code _as part of your post_ and not as an external resource; external resources can disappear or change at any notice. Generally tests against FastAPI should use the bundled TestClient; any reason for not using that?

Comment: I would like to test my approach to running the service too, but I guess I do not need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for testing from [official docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/)

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def read_main():
    return {"msg": "Hello World"}


client = TestClient(app)


def test_read_main():
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"msg": "Hello World"}
```

So, for you example from attached git it can be rewrited to something like this:

```
def test_get_ok():
    response = client.get("/ok")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.text() == 'OK'
```

In a nutshell, it is difficult to describe how to test API correctly, but you can take as an example an [excellent template](https://github.com/s3rius/FastAPI-template) for designing RESTfull API on FastAPI in which there are examples of autotests written just with the Pytest